# Preview and answer your own question problems

Tags: bug, asking, self-answer

I'm using Safari to view the site on my Mac.  (Please withhold all Mac vs. Win vs. Linux commentary!)  And, when private browsing is turned on, I cannot see a preview of my posts.   Additionally, when I click on answer your own question, a blank space is present where the answer box usually appears.

If I turn off Private Browsing, this is not an issue.

Additionally, I do not get any tag suggestions.  (I've just noticed this as I was tagging the post)

Comment: I think the solution is simple: don't use private browsing.

Comment: @MBraedley  True, that would be an answer.  But, perhaps the good people at Stack Exchange can create a more satisfying experience.

Comment: Does it happen with other browsers' private modes?

Comment: @3ventic It does not seem to be affected by Firefox's don't remember history mode.

Comment: @MBraedley - That would be the workaround, but it doesn't make it any less of a bug (Even if its so minor that it gets [status-deferred])

Comment: OMG MAC WINDOWS LINUX COMMENTARY (can't repro on Chrome 34 on Ubuntu)

Comment: @badp It seems to be a Safari private browsing issue. (And, Ubuntu is for hipsters!  :P)